# Concatenate list items

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I need to do something which must be easy enough, but for some reason, I can't get my head around to it.

So, basically, I need to produce a new list that will concatenate the items from three lists with each other.

Please note that all the three lists are currently in a dictionary a.

For clarity, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
def test(phrase):
    a = {}
    tmp = phrase.split(' ')
    for m in xrange(0,len(tmp)):

        a[m] = anagrammes2(tmp[m])
        # The anagram function will spit out the anagrams of the words
        # a[1] = ['mange']
        # a[2] = ['ton, 'ont']
        # a[3] = ['orange','onagre','organe','rongea']

test('Mange ton orange')

#result should be:
['mange ont onagre', 'mange ont orange', 'mange ont orangé', 'mange ont organe', 
 'mange ont rongea', 'mange ton onagre', 'mange ton orange', 'mange ton orangé', 
 'mange ton organe', 'mange ton rongea', 'mangé ont onagre', 'mangé ont orange', 
 'mangé ont orangé', 'mangé ont organe', 'mangé ont rongea', 
 'mangé ton onagre', 'mangé ton orange', 'mangé ton orangé', 
 'mangé ton organe', 'mangé ton rongea']
```

Comment: try zip or zip_longest........

Comment: can you please edit with your code? for we can help?

Comment: Please edit your question text. You are using python, so write your code correctly. If you means list: `list1 = ['a']` etc.

Comment: What Alex said. Python lists are delimited by square brackets `[]`, parentheses `()` are used to delimit tuples.

Comment: Also, your code is a bit confusing: it looks like your list `a` contains itself, but I suspect you don't really mean that.

Comment: Edited to add my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=product#itertools.product):

```
>>> a = [['mange'], ['ton', 'ont'], ['orange','onagre','organe','rongea']]
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [' '.join(x) for x in product(*a)]
['mange ton orange',
 'mange ton onagre',
 'mange ton organe',
 'mange ton rongea',
 'mange ont orange',
 'mange ont onagre',
 'mange ont organe',
 'mange ont rongea']
```

Integrate with your code:

```
def test(phrase):
    anas = [anagrammes2(word) for word in phrase.split(' ')]
    return [' '.join(x) for x in product(*anas)]

test('Mange ton orange')
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. This might seem more than stupid, but how do I integrate it with my current code?

Comment: Try the function I just added.

Comment: Nice one, I've needed to do this kind of thing many times.  It does seem simple, but not so simple to code it.

Comment: It does! Sorry for the late reply and thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are strings:

```
result = tuple(listA[x % len(listA)] + listB[x % len(listB)] + listC[x % len(listC)] for x in range(max(len(listA), len(listB), len(listC))))
```